# Should I Hardcode 81000 String Constants?

Tags: node.js, database, reactjs, constants

I have a list of 81000 (provinces, cities, district etc) to be populated as some input drop down options in a form when user is signing up for an account.

Should I have a hardcoded map for this number of strings? Do I need a database?

What is the maximum number of const strings you think is acceptable? I know 100 constants should be no problem being hardcoded, but what is the borderline when we need a database?

Comment: It would be pretty silly to try to maintain a list of 81K constants, don't you think? And how do you filter them (which you will definitely want to do) when you don't want to list them all at once? If you load 81K constants into a drop down list in a web page, you're going to a) make your page take forever to load; and b) make the list pretty much useless and cumbersome for your users. Try it yourself. Put 1K items in a list on a web page, and see how annoying it is for you to use.

Comment: so the constants are there, but i wont be showing them all at once.  So imagine  a constant json like {placeA : [a1, a2, a3..], placeB: [b1, b2, b3]} and one dropdown only shows placeA  ...not view them all at once, but i guess 81K strings need to be in memory

Comment: 81K strings in memory when you're not going to use them all is a waste of a lot of memory. I would think what I wrote before would have helped you understand how wrong the approach you're considering is without any more needing to be said. I guess it wasn't, so I'll just say it very clearly this time - a list of 81K string constants is absolutely the wrong approach.

Comment: I know but it just seems overkill to put these constants inside a table in a database. What do you think is best approach in this case? Also, what do you think is the limit for hardcoding, should my constants be around 5000, would it be fine?

Comment: Note that these aren't simply arbitrary constants - there are relationships between the data that will be useful to filter by. For instance: what are all the districts in the state? Which cities are under district X? You will want a database so that you can perform such queries.

Comment: The constant here is more like a hash map, a json object: so cityA.provinceA.districtA would be fast too

Comment: If you didn't have that many items a hashmap could be used here - but you really don't want to hardcode all states, districts, provinces, cities... that would be a tremendous amount of data to hard code and load into your application, as has already been noted.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the project like this should be a frontend app + Redis for cache (optional) + DB (your choice)
If you're going to build your app with this 80k rows inside the bundle size will increase ridiculously. And the speed of search and sorting too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you definitely want to consider a database (and probably also some sort of caching) for this use case. The advantages will be:

1. Only loading the relevant data into memory.
2. Breaking the data into logical parts.
3. Being able to map the relationships between the data (eg cities within a province) in a logical way.
4. Points 2 and 3 also make maintenance and updates a lot more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are concerned about the fast loading page don't add **81000 String Constants**. Or else if you don't have any issue with loading you can add **81000 String Constants**.

But if you still want to add **81000 String Constants**, add them in a different js file and load it in asynchronous manner when the website is completely loaded.